# Creating Rich Text editor AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, richtextbox, wysiwyg

I know there are lots of great rich text editors out there that can easily be ported to angular and plenty of discussion on how to do this, but I'd like to create my own.

I have the basic idea down:

- create a text area and watch the input and perform a function as the input changes.  I am familiar with the ngBindhtml directive, only to the extent that I can apply it to an element.

Any idea how I might be able to create a function that would render plain text into `html`?

Comment: Most editors hide the text area, and display the data being typed into a div in its place.  A great way to get started is to look at some really simple examples and then create your directive.

Comment: That's a deceptively simple solution to a seemingly complex problem

Comment: You'll also find this necessary: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/263743/how-to-get-caret-position-in-textarea

Comment: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-tinymce/blob/master/src/tinymce.js ?

Comment: Have you seen [Textangular](http://textangular.com)? If you're looking to make your own there's probably a lot to be learnt from it.

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking to do when I wrote this.  I'll have to look more into this.

Comment: I could recommend you https://github.com/stevermeister/ngWig that even more lightweight than textangular. Good to learn the basics

Answer (score 15):

I've tried it before but ended up using [textAngular](http://textangular.com/).

Basically i replaced the textarea with a iframe, similar to the way tinyMCE does.

The **contenteditable** on a element allow you to replace the textarea and write directly on the div. You would insert all html elements like headers and text this way. You'll have to handle the cursor position on text, apply styles based on buttons and text selection, etc.

Comment: Some opinions before you start to use [textAngular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36079280/rich-text-editor-for-angularjs)

Answer (score 0):

Well, I also came across this and created my own editor as I was required to add features like `Table addition` etc. The repo is still under development but you can some idea [by taking a look at this plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/h2mh1MuJGzxOaYFLU7Up?p=preview). Unlike old answers, I have tried to keep it as a `component` so that it can be reused at many other places as required.

You can `star` [this git repo to stay updated or feel free to add your inputs](https://github.com/shashankvivek/RichTextEditor)

Comment: Removed duplicate ans from other question