# Rich Text Editor for AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, wysiwyg, text-editor, textangular

I use TextAngular which sucks to the core! Anybody using it would know. My users complain every single day :(

I'm looking at alternatives and found some such as Froala ($199) & CKEditor but they require JQuery.

Is there any "good" editor for AngularJS without JQuery that works? I have been searching but couldn't find any. I'm willing to pay too.

Comment: I'm just spiking for an Angular-based rich text editor. Do you have a sec to elaborate on why it sucks so much? Or tweet me @mcbhenwood. Thank you.

Comment: Once you use it for a couple of days, you will realize it. For instance, once has to click once/twice to select the editor!! One can't copy paste if not focussed too unlike other editors.

Comment: Anyone looking for an answer can check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16227917/creating-rich-text-editor-angularjs/49953161#49953161

Comment: CKEditor does not require jQuery and never required it. Since a month or so also CKEditor 5 has an official integration with Angular 2+. For an installation instruction check https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/builds/guides/integration/frameworks/angular.html

Answer (score 119, accepted):

You have a lot of options. But if you don't like it, just write a new editor and share it with us :)

[Angular-Editor](https://github.com/wanming/angular-editor) **->** [Demo](http://wanming.github.io/angular-editor)

[Angular Meditor](https://ghinda.net/angular-meditor/) **->**  [Demo](https://ghinda.net/angular-meditor/)

[Angular trix](https://github.com/sachinchoolur/angular-trix) **->** [Demo](http://sachinchoolur.github.io/angular-trix/)

[ngQuill](https://github.com/KillerCodeMonkey/ngQuill) **->** using [QuillJs](http://quilljs.com/)

[Angular-inline-text-editor](https://github.com/Blitzen/angular-inline-text-editor) **->** [Demo](http://blitzen.github.io/)

You can create a new editor with small changes.

Comment: now thats a wiki :) thanks @hurricane

Comment: Wow thanks! I ended up planning to use TinyMCE. It also supports AngularJS without JQuery.

Comment: @hurricane I would like to use Angular-Editor but tooltip on demo page is Chinees Language. How can I convert it to English? http://wanming.github.io/angular-editor/

Comment: Thanks - Quill looks really great, I'm going to try that direction

Comment: [Editor.js](https://editorjs.io/) it's not an AngularJS library, but you can use it easily

Answer (score 14):

As this is one of the first results on Google when searching for an Angular HTML WYSIWYG editor, I thought I would add to Elaine's comment about her settling on TinyMCE.

There is an Angular module for TinyMCE, ui-tinymce: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-tinymce

Having just tried and failed to get Angular-Trix working, ui-tinymce appears to work quite well. Note that ui-tinymce appears only to work with TinyMCE version **4.3.12** or lower at the moment. The relevant issue is here: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-tinymce/issues/264

Additionally, TinyMCE is also quite well documented: https://www.tinymce.com/docs/

Regarding your no jQuery requirement, the module does not explicitly list it as a dependency, so it may just be dependent on Angular's jqlite (or not at all).